# Why not exclude gradlew files in android project in .gitignore?

Tags: git, android-studio, gradle

In my android project I want to ignore `gradlew` files.

So in my project folder in file `.gitignore`

```
*.iml
.DS_Store
.externalNativeBuild
.gradle
/.idea/**
/.idea/caches/build_file_checksums.ser
/.idea/libraries
/.idea/misc.xml
/.idea/modules.xml
/.idea/workspace.xml
/build
/captures
/gradle/**
/local.properties
/release/*.apk
gradlew
gradlew.bat
```

But it not help. All this file ignores except `gradlew` files. Why?

Comment: Are those files already committed and/or in the index (staged)?

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger this files not commited

Answer (score 0):

To make the Wrapper files available to other developers and execution environments[…](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html#sec:adding_wrapper)

> you’ll need to check them into version control. All Wrapper files including the JAR file are very small in size. Adding the JAR file to version control is expected. Some organizations do not allow projects to submit binary files to version control. **At the moment there are no alternative options to the approach.**

Comment: What is the source of this info?

Comment: @SMR, of course the source is [the official documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html#sec:adding_wrapper).